# Eletrical field Mobius strip

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, gauss-law

I had this question in my mind for months, is there a way to calculate the Electric Field ( Gravitational field as well) generated from a non orientabile Surface ?

Comment: Why do you think a nonorientable surface would produce an electric field? Is the surface carrying a charge?

Comment: Yes consider it uniformed charged and the surface as an insulator

Comment: In a mobius strip this would be rather uninteresting, as for each particular segment considered there are two surfaces. Is there any reason to think it would be different from a flat ring under elemental analysis?

Comment: @JMLCarter It would be different, in final form if not in computation principle. In particular, it might be pretty cool to see how the field lines thread the loop - you wouldn't have an infinitely long, straight field line along the loop's axis for starters in this asymmetrical case.

Comment: Sorry i Misunderstood the question, yes i think it would be different , the simmetry of the ring appear so much simpler.

Comment: By the way i am Not interesting strictly to the elettric field but is more how to calculate it. the surface integral is Not possibile because of the normal vector, the gauss Theorem neither, i do Not see a simmetry to get the electric field out from the integral

Comment: A mobius strip is just a ring with a 180 twist in it; I'm sure the maths will be a bit fiddly, though. Have you tried enclosing it in a hypothetical orientable surface and integrate the charge over that, perhaps weighted for separation? Also this now sounds like a maths question, have you tried the maths site?

Comment: Let's start from the begining, if i have a surface charge density how can i calculate the charge di the mobius strip ?